# next.js Can we set 'public' folder path from next.config.js file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, jamstack, webpack-config

I have a Next.js SSG application that generates two static sites by providing different env variables during export. Can I have two different public folders for these two sites? Can I set public folder inside next.config file?

Comment: why ? you can create two folder in Public folder

Comment: I dont want two applications to share the assets since there are some site specific pdf.